# Update only upgraded packages with rkhunter --propupd

Tags: rkhunter

When upgrading packages on my system with `apt-get`, usually we update the `rkhunter` file database with

```
sudo rkhunter --propupd
```

The drawback is, that this updates the properties of **all** files that are supervised by `rkhunter`. So if **another package** really was **manipulated**, the **information** for this other package **is lost** whenever you update the whole database.

How do I only update the property for the files, that were intentionally upgraded with my package manager, and keep all other file properties intact, so a potential threat is still be reported by `rkhunter`?

Answer (score 1):

1. keep `APT_AUTOGEN="false"` in `/etc/default/rkhunter`
2. This script creates the rkhunter propupdate commands, you would need after an apt run:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# store this file as /usr/local/sbin/rkhunter-auto-update-after-apt

cat /var/lib/rkhunter/db/rkhunter.dat|fgrep "File:" \
    | awk -F ":" '{print $3}' > /tmp/rkhunter-list.txt
NUM=$(grep -n "startup archives unpack" /var/log/dpkg.log|cut -d":" -f1|tail -n1)
tail --lines=+$NUM /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'installed' \
    | awk '{ print $5 }'|sed s/:.*//|xargs dpkg-query -L > /tmp/installed-list.txt

cat /tmp/rkhunter-list.txt | while read BIN; do   
    if grep "^${BIN}$" /tmp/installed-list.txt > /dev/null; then
        if [ "" != "$BIN" ];then
                echo rkhunter --propupd "$BIN"
        fi
    fi
done
```

(on trisquel, the `rkhunter.dat` file has one row less, so the awk needs `{print $2}` there)

call this script after an apt-get run to get the list to update.

If you are satisfied, remove the `echo` and create a hook `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/91rkhunter-post-apt`

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke { "if [ -x /usr/bin/rkhunter ]; then /usr/local/sbin/rkhunter-auto-update-after-apt; fi"; };
```